# How can I get the last candle on the previous day?

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to get the last candle (regular session) of any timeframe (intrday) on the previous day.

I was thinking to use valuewhen but not sure how to do that.

also comparing

```
time < security(tickerid,"D",time[1])
```

is never true, so I can't detect intraday candles excluding today's

for example:

get the last close price of the 5m chart on yesterday's bars.

Answer (score 3):

If you are displaying extended hours on the chart but want them ignored from calcs, the simplest way is to use `security()` because it ignores extended hours. You will see slight discrepancies between the daily close shown here and the one on the last, regular hour bar of the day; they are due to deltas in the intrabar and daily feeds coming from exchanges.

The plot is offset to the left one bar to make it more visible, but it's not absolutely necessary:

```
//@version=4
study("", "", true)
lastClose = security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", close[1], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
plot(lastClose, "Last Close", change(lastClose) ? na : color.blue, offset = - 1)
```

Extended hours appear in gray here:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I was using security , however this is not exactly what I meant.
What I need is to get the open and close of the last day's last Intraday candle for example if 
trading day is 16th I want to get April 15th's 15:55 bar on the 5m chart view,

Comment: Well then instead of saying you wanted "the last candle", you should say in your question that you want the "open and close of the last candle". Can you give details as to what environment this has to work on? Are you using extended hours on your charts or not and should they be included in the calcs? Do the markets you want to use this on all close at the same time?

Comment: I want the last candle open and close yes, I have extended hours on yes, the extended hours should not be calculated, I want it to be generic so not all market close at the same time. Basically I want to be able to get the close price of: the last candle on previous trading session of timeframe X, and the last of timeframe Y, for example the candle of 15:55 for 5m, the 15:45 of 15m and so on . 

In one timeframe I want to know about all the closing candles of pervious day if trading is active, btw, when trading closed its easy I just use security with regular session index 0.

Comment: The problem starts when the trading session opens, I have no way to access the last candle (1 bar before session started) on multiple timeframes at once.